# Auto populate the columns of a sheet based on another column in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a file which contains a column 'Id' with repeatable Id numbers.In the same sheet, I have columns 'Id1' and 'Name1', where the values of column 'Id1' are unique values of those in column 'Id'. Now I want to create a new column 'Name' which will auto populate the values from column 'Name1' for each Id. I tried using VLOOKUP, but it does not seem to get me to an answer. 
Below is a sample dataset:

```
| Id |   |   |   | Id1 | Name1  |
|----|:-:|--:|---|-----|--------|
| 10 |   |   |   | 10  | Robert |
| 10 |   |   |   | 23  | David  |
| 10 |   |   |   |     |        |
| 10 |   |   |   |     |        |
| 10 |   |   |   |     |        |
| 10 |   |   |   |     |        |
| 23 |   |   |   |     |        |
| 23 |   |   |   |     |        |
| 23 |   |   |   |     |        |
| 23 |   |   |   |     |        |
```

I'm expecting my final output to be:

```
| Id |  Name  |   |   | Id1 | Name1  |
|----|:------:|--:|---|-----|--------|
| 10 | Robert |   |   | 10  | Robert |
| 10 | Robert |   |   | 23  | David  |
| 10 | Robert |   |   |     |        |
| 10 | Robert |   |   |     |        |
| 10 | Robert |   |   |     |        |
| 10 | Robert |   |   |     |        |
| 23 | David  |   |   |     |        |
| 23 | David  |   |   |     |        |
| 23 | David  |   |   |     |        |
| 23 | David  |   |   |     |        |
```

Could someone please help me?

**EDIT**
Assuming Id is in column A, Id1 and Name1 in E and F, I entered the formula in cell B2 as `VLOOKUP($A$2, $E$2:$F$3,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Could you share the formula you've tried?

Comment: @dhumphreys I have mentioned the formula in the edit portion

Comment: `$A2` instead of `$A$2` - you need a relative reference there.

Comment: @BigBen My silly mistake. Thanks!